# Train from Budapest to Zagreb - buy in advance or at the train station?

Tags: trains, bookings, croatia, hungary

I'm planning to travel from Budapest to Zagreb by train (IC 200 AGRAM). Should I buy a ticket advance or do they never sell out? Are there discounts for buying the ticket in advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to book a ticket with [Voyages-SNCF](http://uk.voyages-sncf.com/en/), you can immediately see if there are free seats in the train. You can even try to place several orders in your shopping cart (for some reason not more than 6 tickets per order) and estimate how many seats are yet available. For the next few days, the IC 200 seem to have at least 20 seats free, so I would assume that within reason, you can expect to get a ticket on short notice.

The cheapest tickets for the train seem to be the MÁV "Zagreb Special" offer for 8990 HUF or about 29€. If I understand the conditions properly, there is no contingent for the tickets and they are available for sale even on the same day. At least I am able too book a ticket now for the IC 200 departing in about six hours. You can order the ticket online and pick it up at a Hungarian railway station or buy it at the station.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience is a tad rusty, that is, a few years old.

I remember this service only runs a few times per week and, specifically in high season, fills up quickly. So, buying in advance seems the right thing to do.

Comment: There are three daily trains from Budapest to Zagreb, so this does not seem to be a particulary good advice.

Comment: Ha! Things do change, then. :) But, are these direct or indirect connections? db.de only appears to list one direct connection per day.

Comment: These are direct connections, but there are actually only two daily connections, IC200 and IC204. The third I found (the night train from Budpest to Split with stop in Zagreb) only operates twice a week. There are several more connections with one or more train changes. You can find all of these on the DB route planner, so I don't understand what you have been looking for.

Comment: I'm getting different search results today. And I still get only one direct connection on several days: http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/dn?ld=96245&country=DEU&seqnr=1&ident=nv.06302245.1406037438&rt=1&OK#focus

Comment: The deep link to the search result is only valid for a short period.